# How to give styling to components different than App.css in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

Consider my App.css of React app:-

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Now when I am giving any other component background-color of black, then I can see no visible changes ie, App.css's background-color overrides the background-color property of my component. How can I overcome this problem.

Edit:
Here is the CSS code

```
.image {
  float: left;

  padding-left: -5px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.registerCard {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  top: 35%;
  left: 30%;
}


.container {
  display: block;
}
```

I want the background color of registerCard to be set to white, yes I tried !important and it too didn't work.

Here's the App.css file:-

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d1d4c9;
}
```

Here's the component's js file:-

```
import React from 'react'
import img from "./images/bg.png"
import "./register.css"
function Register() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img className = "image" src = {img} />
            <div className="registerCard" >
                <form action="/action_page.php" >
                        <div class="container">
                            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                            <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                            <hr/>


                            <label for="firstName"><b>First Name</b></label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required/>
                            <br/>
                            <label for="lastNamel"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required/>
                            <br/>
                            <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required/>
                            <br/>
                            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required/>
                            <br/>
                            <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required/>
                            <br/>
                            <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" /> Remember me
                            </label>
                            
                            <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" >Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register
```

I have imported the CSS file to the component's js file, should I need to import it to App.js too??

Comment: How you are setting the background color to the component, can you please add some code here ?

Comment: @swapnesh I edited the question

Comment: Can you add the js / jsx part as well ?

Comment: is there any reason for you to declare bg-color for every single element in the app ?

Comment: @İlker no but I got similar problems in other projects as well so I taught of ending this doubt for once and all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tricks to overcome your problem. Try followings.

1. Make sure to import your component's style(css, scss, sass, less) file to the component file.
2. Be more specific when selecting the selector. (Try these links: [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp), [css combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)).
3. Use `!important` rule at the end of css rule which you want to override. Check example below.

App.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Component.css

```
.class-to-add-style {
  background-color: red !important; /* this rule will override the rule from App.css */
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I edited the question in case you need more details

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have different answers because you were not very specific...

Anyway I think this happens because you import your App.css in your Ap.js file, but don't do the same with your other components.

Consider your component is named **MyComponent**:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./MyComponent.css";
    
function MyComponent() {
  return(
    <h1>example</h1>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```